# iterated loop not consistently fully iterating

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write an iterated loop with a step size of 175 but each time I run my program the loop iterates at different lengths. Everytime I run it increases the final iteration by the step size. Not sure whats going on.

For context I am integrating an ODE with a Runge-Kutta subroutine.

```
do i= 175,17500,175
call rkf45(real(i,wp),ts,te,y,esp1,esp2,h,hmin,175._wp,dy,flag,neqn)
q(i)=y(1)
ts=te
te=te+175.0_wp
hmax=te-ts
write(*,*)i,q(i)
enddo
```

final outputs for 3 consecutive runs

```
11200   257478.60158947381
13650   431868.79246271809
17500   808062.17349709466
```

not sure what to try, tried initializing i to 0 before and after.

Comment: I am afraid it will be impossible to answer this without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My only complete stab in the dark is to ask what happens when you compile and run it with all the runtime checks turned on - with gfortran compile with -fcheck=all -g

Comment: We really need a full piece of code. Show how you declare your variables and how you define their values. Tell us where the `rkf45` subroutine comes from. It might be a well known library, but please specify exactly from where you got it.

Comment: What you have described is often the result of using an uninitialized variable or writing to an out-of-bounds array location.  If you're using gfortran try adding the `-Wall -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero` options.